# Using NSTimer across view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer, appdelegate

I want to use a counter in my app that works across views. I have a detail view where you can see the counter, but I also have a configuration view.

The timer is used to do a calculation. The configuration view is there to change the calculation, so the timer needs run while on other view.

I have read some tips on using NSTimer in the AppDelegate, but I don't know how to implement it. Is there any guides or tutorials out there? Any link is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try to implement a Singleton class? Just wrap the NSTimer instance in a singletone and you'll be able to access it anywhere.

Comment: That is something I saw in another question. Is there some code examples you can send me to?